# Installation and persistence on an SSD

Tags: system-installation, hardware, ssd

First of all, sorry about the English, it's not my first language.

I'd like to install Elementary OS on an SSD, this one : https://www.amazon.fr/Kingston-SSDNow-UV400-Disque-SATA/dp/B01FJ4UN76/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1475087100&sr=8-1&keywords=kingston+ssd+120

Moreover, like I said in the title, I'd like to be able to save my work on the SSD, plug it into other computers and take it everywhere I need !

I already created a persistence installation of Debian on a HDD, but I guess the procedure should be slightly different with ElementaryOS and a SSD.

I am running W10 at the time btw.

I already searched for threads or tutorials on how to make a persistent installation of ElementaryOS but never found something useful ...

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: I don't understand, what do you think is different between a normal and a "persistent" installation?

Comment: I mean, you surely have to do something more to get persistence, don't you ?

Comment: Anyone please ? :(

Answer (score 1):

Just install it on the ssd normally. The external ssd is not like a USB stick. Just install it and test it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just download the ISO ans use unetbootin ? And then what should I do to make the installation persistent and do not loose my work?

Comment: Hi guys, I created a live USB key with Elementary OS on it, booted on it and tried to install EOS on my SSD, however when creating the partitions I got an error like this : “… offset of 3584 bytes from minimum alignment …” Do you guys know what to do about this ? I'm currently trying to solve this problem with partitions tools ...

Comment: @TierOne that error happens a lot with the newer ssd/hdd, I recommend you to delete the partition that came by default and create all the partitions you need beforehand, /, /home and swap(optional) if you have enough ram don't do it unless you like to hibernate your system. After that install it again and all should be fine. I recommend GParted for the process of creating the partitions.

Comment: Ok that is exactly what i've done using Mini tools partition wizard. I made the installation on the ssd now I'll try to boot on it, hope everything goes well. I'll change the boot order. Keep you update asap

Comment: My laptop is not booting on my ssd... All this is starting to p*ss me off. I changed the boot order, I put my laptop drive after everything and still, it won't boot on my ssd...

Comment: I went into the parameters of W10, showed up the interface on which you can choose to access to the BIOS and tried to boot on the SSD and when I want to, it tells me :  no bootable device detected -- inser boot disk... "

Comment: @TierOne try to disable fast boot, at this point it's only what i can think of, since you use W10 and fast boot usually brings trouble.

Comment: Ok, I will try this, thank you man. However, everything should be ok, right ?

Comment: @TierOne yes, you did the installation successfully without error outputs, the problem is not on your ssd almost certainly. Now you just need to try to find the reason why your laptop is not booting from the SSD as expected.

Comment: Even with fastboot off, the laptop won't boot on the ssd... I'm getting tired of all this wtf.

Comment: Please guys, I really need to run eOS or another distro before tomorrow

Comment: I noticed that when I want to proceed to the installation, eOS tells me that there is no modification of the partitions tables and that any files systems creation has been planified ... Although, there are the two partitions I've created before ... I translated the message from french to english. Tell me if you don't understand it !

Comment: This is not a "help me!" forum. You make a good question and your are likely to get an answer. Your original question is unintelligible and the follow up from this comments its worst.